# Xulrunner crash when running with underprivileged user

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, headless, xvfb

I use SlimerJs as an headless browser on a server. 
Because the server have no xserver I used xvfb to run it.

The command goes something like this:

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" slimerjs-0.10.0pre/slimerjs \
script.js --debug=yes "/tmp/file986Iww" "/tmp/file28bAEv" "pdf"
```

The file `script.js` takes a file name for input, a file name for output and a format to convert to, using slimer's printer capability.

My problem is that when running as root, it works fine. But when I let apache do the work it fails and get stucks.

Apache runs under `www-data` user and group. This is the output of the previous command:

```
slimerjs-0.10.0pre/xulrunner/xulrunner -app slimerjs-0.10.0pre/application.ini --profile /tmp/slimerjs.gRAJJar6 -no-remote script.js --debug=yes /tmp/file986Iww /tmp/file28bAEv pdf
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
JavaScript warning: resource://slimerjs/slUtils.jsm, line 154: JavaScript 1.7's let blocks are deprecated
JavaScript error: jar:file:///var/www/project/slimerjs-0.10.0pre/xulrunner/omni.ja!/components/XULStore.js, line 66: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIProperties.get]
** stuck forever here **
```

The line 66 of `XULStore.js` is:

```
65. Services.obs.addObserver(this, "profile-before-change", true);
66. this._storeFile = Services.dirsvc.get("ProfD", Ci.nsIFile);
67. this._storeFile.append(STOREDB_FILENAME);
```

Trying to see what is wrong with strace show me that it is stuck in some kind of loop...

I see no reasons why this user can't run this binary.
**How can I debug what permission is missing or what is going wrong with xulrunner ?**

I did not post the strace because it's quite heavy, feel free to ask for it if you feel it may contain relevant informations.

```
$ uname -a
Linux *host* 3.10-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.10.5-1~bpo70+1 (2013-08-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not have permissions to access or write to the profile directory you are attempting to retrieve.

Although you are (presumably) attempting to set the profile directory via `--profile /tmp/slimerjs.gRAJJar6` the [SlimerJS documentation](https://docs.slimerjs.org/current/configuration.html) indicates this should be `-profile` (single dash)

By default, if you omit the profile option, as it appears you are doing due to the double dash vs. single dash, then "SlimerJS [will] create a temporary profile each time you launch it" by making a new directory in "$HOME/.innophi/slimerjs/"

Since you are attempting to run this as `www-data` check their home directory and verify that you can create and access files in the SlimerJS default directory path or use `-profile` instead of `--profile` and verify you can create and access files in the specified folder.

Comment: Their was a lot more than that but you put me on the right track. By using `strace` and `grep EACC` I saw what where the files causing trouble. Profile was indeed involved. I had to create and chmod many files in order for it to work.